# Service Bus Client: how to concurrently process messages in C#

Tags: c#, concurrency, azureservicebus

I'm on a task of receiving messages from a data provider who is using Azure Service Bus.
Here is my codes in a nutshell, which does its job.

```
var _serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient(_options.FullyQualifiedNamespace, token);

var options = new ServiceBusProcessorOptions
{
    AutoCompleteMessages = false,
    MaxConcurrentCalls = 1,
    PrefetchCount = 1,
    MaxAutoLockRenewalDuration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20, 0),
};

_serviceBusProcessor = _serviceBusClient.CreateProcessor(queueName, options);

_serviceBusProcessor.ProcessMessageAsync += messageHandler.DispatchAsync;
_serviceBusProcessor.ProcessErrorAsync += messageHandler.ErrorHandlerAsync;

......

public class MessageHandler : IMessageHandler
{
    public async Task DispatchAsync(ProcessMessageEventArgs args)
    {
        // Codes to process the message, sometimes it may take around 10 mis to process a message
        if (args.Message.Subject == "") { TransformData(args.Message.Body); }
        ......
        await args.CompleteMessageAsync(args.Message);
    }
}
```

Looks like the message can be processed once at a time with above codes. Sometimes it takes more than 10 mins to process a message, which blocks other messages to be processed.

I tried increasing **MaxConcurrentCalls** to more than 1 like 2 or 4, but it seemed not working.
How can I write codes to concurrently process messages please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Increasing MaxConcurrentCalls to the number of messages that you would like to process in parallel is the right approach.  You'll see your message handler invoked multiple times, each with a different message - assuming messages are available to read.  What makes you think that it wasn't working?

Comment: I doubt on message size , why don’t you send 100 messages in parallel but just simple text say your name and print it with thread id in console as in a handler

Comment: Hi @JesseSquire, looks like it's working only if I set PrefetchCount to more than 1, and then 2 processors are processing same messages.....

Comment: Hi @MohammadArshad, how to implement it then? I have no idea how server end works. how to send message to myself?

Comment: Two processors are physically unable to process the same message unless you've let the lock expire, in which case one will fail when they try to complete the message.    Prefetch has nothing to do with concurrency, it just reduces the network lag when streaming in messages - but messages held in prefetch cannot have their locks renewed, so use with caution.

Comment: Just for context, are you using the Sessions functionality of Service Bus? I've seen unexpectedly slow throughput when using Sessions incorrectly. But I won't bother expand on that if you're not using them. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-sessions